# AppleScript resize image and save with new name

Tags: applescript, filemaker

I'm calling an Applescript from within FilemakerPro.
These are the things I try to achieve:

- An image is stored within a container field.
- It stores it's name and path in separate fields.

An Applescript is being activated to perform these actions:

- It retrieves the data from FilemakerPro
- It checks if there is a folder with the same name as the field "calculate_merk_id"
- If not, it creates the folder
- It creates a new imagefile which name should have "__small" added to his name after it has been resized to 155 x  134, and stores it in this folder
- It creates a new imagefile which name should have "__large" added to his name after it has been resized to 400 x  400, and stores it in this folder

The first error I receive is that it cannot retrieve the dimensions of the image. Furthermore, it won't create my resized images ... Anyone who wants to give me a hand in the right direction, please?

```applescript
set pad to cell "ServerImagePath" of current record
set filenaam to cell "afbeelding_local_vol_pad" of current record
set foldernaam to cell "calculate_merk_id" of current record
set volle_foldernaam to cell "ServerImageFolder" of current record
set volle_filenaam to cell "ServerImageFile" of current record

set target_small_width to 155
set target_small_height to 134
set target_large_width to 400
set target_large_height to 400

tell application "Finder"
if not exists volle_foldernaam then
          make new folder at pad with properties {name: foldernaam}
   end if

   duplicate filenaam to volle_foldernaam with replacing

   tell application "Image Events"
      launch
      set this_image to filenaam
      copy dimensions of this_image to {W, H}

      if target_small_width is greater than target_small_height then

         if W is greater than H then

            set the scale_length to (W * target_small_height) / H
            set the scale_length to round scale_length rounding as taught in school
         else

             set the scale_length to target_small_height
          end if

       else if target_small_height is greater than target_small_width then

          if H is greater than W then

             set the scale_length to (H * target_small_with) / W
             set the scale length to round scale_length rounding as taught in school
          else

            set the scale_length to target_small_width
          end if

       else 
           set the scale_length to target_small_height
       end if

       scale this_image to size scale_length

       pad this_image to dimensions {target_small_width, target_small_height}


       save this_image as this_name & "__small"

       close this_image

   end tell

end tell
```

Comment: @mklement0 what did you change? The formatting is still wrong and there is a tag in the title.

Comment: @Mark: I changed 'Apple script' to 'AppleScript', because that's the name of both the technology and a script instance, as in this case. (Generally: nothing wrong with a tag in the title, if it's germane to the title). There was no syntax highlighting previously, so I added `<!-- language: lang-applescript -->`; note that while AppleScript is not officially supported and the highlighting is therefore sometimes incorrect, it is still preferable to having NO highlighting. Is that the wrong formatting you refer to?

Comment: No, the indenting is a little off and AFAIK there shouldn't be tags in the title according to the guidelines (but those are subject to change and I might be behind).

Comment: Sorry if my title wasn't along with the guidelines. I'm more about how it works in a good way, rather than following the exact letter ... Anyway, I still didn't get it to work ...

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to open the image

```
set this_image to filenaam
```

should be

```
set this_image to open filenaam
```

Comment: Then it fails with an error: The dimensions of missing value can't be retrieved ...

Comment: It looks like the variable filenaam is not correct. Try `log filenaam`. Is it a correct filepath?

Comment: Where are logs stored? If I used
    set this_image to filenaam
It showed the correct file

Comment: Oops, I see you write it in Filemaker Pro. There could be a problem with the inside FMPro scripting. Try it in Applescript Editor first for debugging. What file type is it? Image Events supports only BMP/JPEG/JPEG2/PICT/PNG/PSD/QuickTime Image/TIFF.

Comment: It is a JPG file.
Hmm, will try to convert it to the correct parameters in Applescript Editor. I'll keep you posted ...

Comment: Hmmm, the log returns the correct file, but it doesn't find the Dimensions on _missing value_

Comment: What is the result of opening the image? It should be `--> image "filename.jpg"`  Another idea would be to test the file header. May be the file is broken. Try `do shell script "file " & quoted form of filenaam`

Comment: Hmmm, you start losing me ... If I tell Finder to open it, it opens it in preview. But I did notice that in Finder itself, it doesn't show the dimensions either in the info window... Might that be a bad sign?
Also, it seems I can get the dimensions into a field in Filemaker, is it good practice to use those ...?

Answer (score 0):

Why not do this natively in FileMaker? FM 12 and later have the GetThumbnail() function. A script could calculate a re-sized image into a global field, then export the image from the global field. Completely cross-platform will work on OSX and Windows, even FileMaker Go.

```
Set Field [ photo_temp_g ; GetThumbnail ( photo_original ; width ; height ) ]
Commit Record/Request []
Export Field Contents [ photo_temp_g ; “<filename>” ]
```